# Shape visibility in windows phone methods not recognized by Visual Studio

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app on Windows phone using Visual Studio 2013 and .Net 4.5.1. The problem is that Visual Studio can't recognize methods `IsVisible` and `Visible` in class `Shape`.

I included namespaces `System.Windows.Shapes`  and `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks` which are also not recognized by Visual Studio; I got these methods and namespaces from the Windows Phone Dev website.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post your code here please?

Comment: @ChrisShao http://pastebin.com/zn8MQxE3

Comment: Sorry, the url is unavailable for me. Because I am in China.

Comment: http://ideone.com/A7fCcN

Comment: I have read your code. the namespace: Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes is used by Windows Store App and Windows Phone 8.1 App. Your app is Windows Phone 8, isn't it? So you can't use this namespace.

Comment: Yes windows phone 8.1 app,ok thanks how about method IsVisible still not recognizable what shoud I do ?

Comment: I update the answer, please read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Visibility` instead of `IsVisible` OR `Visible`.And in your code, just like this:

```
private void Flag1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(Flag1.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
        Flag1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Flag2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Flag3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Flag4.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PhoneApp1.MainPage.winners.AFirstPlace= "Brazil";       
    }
    else if (Flag1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        Flag1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PhoneApp1.MainPage.winners.AFirstPlace = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Karim Gabr You are welcome. Please mark it as answer.